# How to remove spaces between parenthesis?

Tags: search

I have a text that looks like this

```
" original
  call minpac#add('morhetz / gruvbox')

" desired
  call minpac#add('morhetz/gruvbox')
```

How can I limit vim pattern search within parentheses?

I tried `'<,'>s/ //g` in visual selection mode, **but** the problem is it also removes the indentation at the start as a sideffect. I am looking for a pattern search variation which would only work inside the parenthesis.

I am looking for something in lines of `'<,'>s/ //gc` where I can tell vim its `n` for first match and `y` for all others? I am not even sure if  something like this is even possible in vim.

Comment: What about a line like this `X Y (WWW 22(X Y [A 90] )) #`? Can there be unmatched parenthesis? What about parenthesis inside quotes, should they be considered? Pairs of parenthesis that span multiple lines? Please always think of edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can process in two times with mixing `:substitute` with `substitute()`, thanks to `\=`

```
:%s/(\zs.*\ze)/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '', 'g')/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you desired output is:

```
" desired
  call minpac#add('morhetz/gruvbox')
```

And you are not against doing it a bit interactively...

1. put your cursor on the line before or inside `'morhets / gruvbox'` and do `vi'` to select everything inside a string.
2. run the command `:s/\%V\s\+//g` (it should look like `:'<,'>s/\%V\s\+//g`) on a command line

`:help \%V` -- match inside visual area.

Or, alternatively, you can limit your regex with a column:

```
:s/\%>20c\s*//g
```

`:h \%>c` -- match after a specific column.

Comment: Note: `\s` after `\V%` means ` ` (SPACE) for vim, so `:'<,'>s/\%V\s\+//g` is same as `:'<,'>s/\%V \+//g`, And `\+` seems not necessary at all in this case, Tested `Vim 8.2`, `NVim 4.4`

Comment: Not really. Check help for `\s`

Comment: yes it removes `TAB`s to